How to configure an Activity to continue in Azure Data Factory when an previous Activity is Deactivated
I have stored procedure activity that I would like to complete even if the previous activity is deactivated. In the image below you can see that the activity 'Full Load' is de-activated.

As a result of the 'Full Load' activity being de-activated, the Stored Procedure 'Log Process Throughput' is failing with the following error:

The setting for the stored procedure is as follows:

I can see that the problem is with
activity('Full Load').output.rowsCopied

I need the stored procedure activity to execute even though the 'Full Load' activity is de-activated.
Can someone let me know if that is possible?
Applying @activity('Full Load')?.output?.rowsCopied
Gives the following error:


Can you try using :
@activity('Full Load')?.output?.rowsCopied
And you can use collasce to check whether it is null and provide value accordingly

Hi @Nandan, thanks for getting in touch. I'm not sure what you mean by 'use collasce to check whether it is null and provide value accordingly'?

For now, try the provided expression as is within your pipeline and try executing it. What I meant is in case if the full load activity is disabled, there wont be any value and in case if you want to pass some value in such cases, you can use if else or collasce function to provide a value as an alternative

I have applied your suggested expression. I have updated the question with the error that it produces

Hi @Nandan, I copied your suggestion incorrectly. When I copied it correctly it was a success. Thank you very much
